# Is there any iOS emulator for Flutter Windows?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, windows, mobile-development

I am currently doing a project. I can use the Android Studio for Android side but I don't know how to test the app for iOS. I have both Android and iOS device to test the app, just I don't know the emulator that can be used for iOS. Can anyone help me?

I saw someone said using XCode but I think XCode only can be used in macOS not Windows.

Comment: No, you need to use xcode tools to generate an emulator for iOS, therefore you require a macbook. There is no escaping that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best guess and I've also used it: [pub.dev/packages/device-preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview)
Another similair solution is to use the flutter inspector. Find the bar with "Flutter inspector" in it and click on 'Toggle Platform Mode'. It will open a popup where you can change the device. Some people like to use a MacOS windowed virtual machine to use XCode emulator (In this case I'd recommend VMWare). Last option is not probably the solution you're looking for but most professinoal programmers will just buy a MacBook.